# How do I determine the type of curve formed by the intersection of the cone $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ with the plane $2x+z=3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I determine the type of curve formed by the intersection of the cone $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ with the plane $2x+z=3$?

Can I eliminate this by using the plane equation z or x in the equation of the cone?

Comment: The intersection curve of the cone... **with what** ? And what has that plane to do with all this? Also, perhaps a new nick name would be nice.

Comment: Pretty sure you sub $z=3-2x$ and then proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic definition of a conic section: the intersection of a cone and a plane. This plane doesn’t intersect the vertex of the cone (the origin), so the resulting conic section is non-degenerate. You’ve either got an ellipse, a parabola, or a hyperbola depending on the angle of the plane relative to that of the side of the cone. The normal to the plane, $\langle2,0,1\rangle$, makes an angle $\theta$ with the $z$ axis with $\cos\theta={\langle2,0,1\rangle\cdot\langle0,0,1\rangle\over\|\langle2,0,1\rangle\|}=\frac1{\sqrt5}<\frac1{\sqrt2}=\cos\frac\pi4$, so the plane intersects both nappes of the cone and forms a hyperbola.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating $z$ is a good idea.

You know that $z=3-2x$,

so substitute to get $x^2+y^2=(3-2x)^2$.

Rearrange and get it into a recognisable form...